# Record speaker output with Audio Unit

Tags: macos, core-audio, audio-recording

**What I'm trying to do:** Record the speaker output using Audio Units.

**What I have tried:** I'm using Apples sample code "RecordAudioToFile", *(http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/RecordAudioToFile)* which does exactly what I want, except that it use the microphone as input.

It thought changing *`kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice`* to *`kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice`* would solve my problem, but with the change, I get no calls to the callback method.

See my code here (line 361 has the change above):
*http://www.rdahl.se/misc/DCAudioFileRecorder_modified.cpp*.

**HELP NEEDED!**

- What do I have to do to solve my problem?
- Tips on good guides on audio unit development?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an output device (speakers) as an input device.

AFAIK the solution employed by software like [Jack OS X](http://www.jackosx.com/) is to appear as a fake audio device and redirect a program's output to this pseudo-device.

Comment: can you give more info, how to do that?